# color change Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, loops

I am trying to

- Retrieve 2 columns from MySQL and display them in HTML table
- When clicked on Name which is in the table header i want to change the color of all the contacts.

what I hv done-
callin a javascript on `tableRows` id to change color,but it only changes the the color of 1st row.

```
<?php
  while($row_color_test = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_color_test))
  {
    ?>
      <tr id="tableRows">
        <td><?php echo $row_color_test['name'] ; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_color_test['phone']; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php 
  }
    ?>
```

Javascript Function

```
function changecolor()
    {
     document.getElementById("tableRows").style.color="red";
    }
```

any idea why it happening although all the rows are dynamically created by while loop so all hv the same id and therefore,CSS rule sud apply on them.

Or is there a better way to do it??I hv to use Javascript only

Comment: id should be unique to one element in the DOM, if you want to select multiple elements use `class` and `document.getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but it only changes the the color of 1st row.

Right. The `tableRows` `id` is on the **row**, and `id` values **must** be unique on the page. You can't have more than one element (row, in this case) with the same `id`. If you do, most browsers just ignore the `id` on subsequent elements on the page — so you're only seeing one element updated.

You *could* use a `class` instead:

```
<tr class="tableRows" ...
```

...and do this [on most browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector):

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".tableRows");
var index;
for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
    ilst[index].style.color = "red";
}
```

But it would be better still to just set a class on the table and use CSS rules to turn the rows red instead.

```
document.getElementById("id_of_the_table").className += " foo";
```

...with this CSS:

```
.foo tr {
    color: "red"
}
```

Comment: Yes. Or if an ID is needed, create unique IDs (e.g. concatenate a counter).